# symbol √ in C language

Tags: c, windows

How to write this symbol √ in C language?

I get this error everytime

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   16 |     if (znamienko == 'm) {
      |                      ^~~
```

i tried 0x221A method didnt work for me, i am trying to make calculator project:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double cislo1, cislo2, vysledek;
    char znamienko;

    printf("Napíš prvé číslo: ");
    scanf("%lf", &cislo1);

    printf("Napíš znamienko (+, -, *, /, ^, √): ");
    scanf(" %c", &znamienko);
    znamienko = getchar();
    getchar();
    
    if (znamienko == '√') {
        vysledek = sqrt(cislo1);
        printf("Výsledok odmocnenia: %lf\n", vysledek);
    } else {
        printf("Napíš druhé číslo: ");
        scanf("%lf", &cislo2);

        switch (znamienko) {
            case '+':
                vysledek = cislo1 + cislo2;
                printf("Výsledok sčítania: %lf\n", vysledek);
                break;
            case '-':
                vysledek = cislo1 - cislo2;
                printf("Výsledok odčítania: %lf\n", vysledek);
                break;
            case '*':
                vysledek = cislo1 * cislo2;
                printf("Výsledok násobenia: %lf\n", vysledek);
                break;
            case '/':
                if (cislo2 != 0) {
                    vysledek = cislo1 / cislo2;
                    printf("Výsledok delenia: %lf\n", vysledek);
                } else {
                    printf("Chyba: Nejde deliť nulou.\n");
                }
                break;
            case '^':
                vysledek = pow(cislo1, cislo2);
                printf("Výsledok umocnenia: %lf\n", vysledek);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Chybné znamienko.\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i tried 0x221A method and i am trying if you just start the code and write first number then it will ask you for the sign in mathematics if u write √ it will just continue the code but in this case it will just say Incorrect sign

Comment: That is not a character in most simpler encodings like ASCII. You're probably editing your source in UTF-8, and that character needs multiple bytes to encode in UTF-8, and therefore its use in literal character (single-quote `''`) is implementation defined. To be fully compliant with "pure" C all characters needs to be only one single byte.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is in code in `znamienko == '√'` part, but it is multibyte or utf16, so compiler displays only first part of it, which is apparently `m`

Comment: I've never seen a keyboard with a `√` key, so the question may be moot.  Even if you write the program so that it can correctly receive a `√` on its input as a wide or multi-byte character, how do you anticipate a user will *enter* one?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Alt-codes, copy-paste, alternate keyboard layouts...

Comment: No √  is a character in UTF-8 and ISO C. wchar_t was made for this.

Comment: That wasn't a challenge, @user2357112.  I know that there are various environment-specific ways to accomplish it. But they are not widely known, nor easy to remember for most. Tying a program feature to being able to enter a `√` character into a text UI produces bad UX.

Comment: A hack is to use another symbol, after all `^` is a convenient symbol that does not mean power (it is XOR). For example use the `_` underscore or the `|` pipe to indicate `√`, and move on to the real work.

Answer (score -1):

`wchar_t` is what you need. For multi-byte chars.

Here:

```c
#include <wchar.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double cislo1, cislo2, vysledek;
    wchar_t znamienko;

    printf("Napíš prvé číslo: ");
    wscanf("%lf", &cislo1);

    printf("Napíš znamienko (+, -, *, /, ^, √): ");
    wscanf(" %c", &znamienko);
    znamienko = getchar();
    getchar();

    if (znamienko == '√') {
        vysledek = sqrt(cislo1);
        printf("Výsledok odmocnenia: %lf\n", vysledek);
    } else {
        printf("Napíš druhé číslo: ");
        wscanf("%lf", &cislo2);

        switch (znamienko) {
            case '√':
                printf("sqrtoot()\n");
                break;
            case '+':
                vysledek = cislo1 + cislo2;
                printf("Výsledok sčítania: %lf\n", vysledek);
                break;
            case '-':
                vysledek = cislo1 - cislo2;
                printf("Výsledok odčítania: %lf\n", vysledek);
                break;
            case '*':
                vysledek = cislo1 * cislo2;
                printf("Výsledok násobenia: %lf\n", vysledek);
                break;
            case '/':
                if (cislo2 != 0) {
                    vysledek = cislo1 / cislo2;
                    printf("Výsledok delenia: %lf\n", vysledek);
                } else {
                    printf("Chyba: Nejde deliť nulou.\n");
                }
                break;
            case '^':
                vysledek = pow(cislo1, cislo2);
                printf("Výsledok umocnenia: %lf\n", vysledek);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Chybné znamienko.\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You should know that wchar_t is a compiler specific type. So it's behavior could be different. The above compiled for me with gcc.

More: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character

Comment: Why does your code use `wscanf()` to set `znamienko` and then immediately uses `getchar()` to do the same?

Comment: Beyond it not making sense in general, you can't mix wide and narrow operations on the same stream.

Comment: Plus you're still comparing a wide character against a character literal that's too small to hold the square root character, just like OP. Should be  `znamienko == L'√'` instead. Same for the `switch`.

Comment: Why does the code test for `'√'` but then include it as a `case` in the `else` block?

Comment: "The above compiled for me with gcc" If you were paying attention, you should have noticed that gcc gave you a warning. Exactly the same warning OP is asking about. In exactly the same place. You have not changed it at all. And on top of that, a ton of other warnings.

Comment: w_char is compiler specific. I didn't fix OP's code perfectly - but you _can_ mix w_char and char. However, you are taking the risk the compiler's implementation is using UTF8. I dont know of a compiler which doesnt use UTF-8 - but their might be one out there.

Comment: As for the warnings - yes - who cares? It's for a school project clearly and he wants to know if he can put a UTF-8 char in his code. YOU CAN. period. If he wanted a book on unicode character handling and dealing with interactive chars beyond ASCII look at ncurses. I've seen shipping product with 1000s of warnings. Who cares. it either tests or it doesn't.